# Inline the value of an Org-mode property?

Tags: org-mode

Quite a while ago, I've created a word document where I defined variables, did
calculations with them, and had the results printed inline into the
document. Example output, where the result has been calculated from
variables `a = 1` and `b = 2`:

“The result of 1 plus 2 is 3”

For org-mode, I found that I can defined properties, and do basic
calculations with them. *But how do I output their values into running
text, i.e. without using a table.*

Naturally, I want the calculated value to be visible in the text buffer
right in EMACS. If it’s only possible to see the value in an exported
PDF, for example, then that’s not interesting.

Answer (score 7):

You have to pick a language, and then `src_<lang>{code}`. For example,

```
src_octave{2+3}
```

When you evaluate that (with `C-c C-c`), you should see:

```
src_octave{2+3} {{{results(=5=)}}}
```

And `5` will be exported to PDF. If you want to use variables defined elsewhere, you can use the `session` option.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC octave :results output :session foo
a = 1;
b = 2;
#+END_SRC
#+RESULTS:
```

And then elsewhere:

```
src_octave[:session foo]{a+b} {{{results(=3=)}}}
```

See http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to have the result inlined into text in the org mode buffer, without ugly code disrupting reading-flow. I normally don't use export. I use org-mode to write documents that are readable right in EMACS.

Comment: I would make this a non-Org question: how do I make text invisible between two tags, including tags. Ex: `<hide> foo </hide>`. Then put the inline code where it becomes invisible. This may be built into Org, for example using link syntax. I'd also try this on the mailing list where there are more eyes.